# Need FileWriter to write to next line after a certain ammount of characters from long String

Tags: java, user-interface, filewriter

I have made a Note program using FileWriter. It works perfectly, except if I write a long note the note will just be saved in one line.
Is there any way I can make it so the program will write to the next line after a certain ammount of characters?
This is my code:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Double.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Note extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JTextArea area;
JTextField title;
JLabel titleTxt, noteTxt;
JButton save, clear, exit;
FileWriter writer=null;
PrintWriter gen =null;
Scanner reader =null;
boolean append = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Note window = new Note();
    window.setTitle("Note");
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.createGUI();
    window.setSize(300,250);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void createGUI() {
setLayout ( new FlowLayout() );

    titleTxt = new JLabel("Title:");
    add(titleTxt);

    title = new JTextField(30);
    add(title);

    noteTxt = new JLabel("Note:");
    add(noteTxt);

    area = new JTextArea(5,25);
    area.setLineWrap(true);
    area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane field = new JScrollPane(area);
    add(field);

    save = new JButton("Save");
    save.addActionListener(this);
    add(save);

    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    add(clear);

    exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(this);
    add(exit);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == save){
        Save();
        area.setText("");
        title.setText("");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == clear){
        area.setText("");
        title.setText("");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == exit){
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private void Save(){

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    String outTxt = "Note is saved";

    try{

        //FileWriting
        File file = new File(date+".txt");
        writer = new FileWriter(file,append);
        writer.write("Tid: "+timeStamp+"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.write(title.getText()+"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");

        writer.write(area.getText()+"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.close();

    }


        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                outTxt="File Not Found";
            }

            catch (Exception e){
                outTxt="Error";
            }
            finally {
                if (reader!=null)reader.close();
                showMessageDialog(null, outTxt);
            }

        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do something like so:

```
 try{

        //FileWriting
        File file = new File(date+".txt");
        writer = new FileWriter(file,append);
        writer.write("Tid: "+timeStamp+"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.write(title.getText().replaceAll("(.{50}[^ ]+)\\s+", "$1\r\n")+"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");

        writer.write(area.getText().replaceAll("(.{50}[^ ]+)\\s+", "$1\r\n")+"\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.write("\r\n");
        writer.close();

    }
```

This will replace 50 characters and any subsequent non white space characters and put them in a group and replace them with the same group and a `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you also know a way to make it so the words won't cut if a word is char nr. 47-52?

Comment: I get the error "illegal escape character" at the "s" in "(.{50}[^ ]+)\s+" ?

Comment: @SlyTech404: Sorry my bad. See how it goes now.